# Proving that $\frac {\cos(π + x)\cos(-x)}{\cos(π-x)(\frac{π}{2}+x)} = \cot^2(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove:
>
> $$\frac {\cos(\pi + x)\cos(-x)}{\cos(\pi - x)\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}+x)} = \cot^2(x)$$

I tried to solve the left hand side but got the answer as $-\cot(x)$ instead.

Comment: You mean $\pi$ when you write $pi$, right?

Comment: yes, edited the question

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

1. $\cos(\pi+x)=\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$.
2. $\cos(-x)=\cos x$
3. $\cos (\frac {\pi} 2+x)=-\sin x$

Comment: $\cos(-x)=\cos x$...

Comment: edited the question, had missed a term in denominator

Answer (score 1):

Is the 1st term in the denominator perhaps supposed to be $\cos({\frac{\pi}{2} - x})$? Otherwise your answer of $-\cot (x)$ is correct.

Comment: nop. that's what the question is. I guess the question is wrong then.

Comment: Yes, I don't see how the answer can be $\cot ^2(x)$ if the question is as it is.